# Platform For Selling Videos Online?

Tags: video, security, ecommerce, invoicing

I'd like to set up an online store where I can sell some video courses ( 3 or 4 with a 10 minutes maximum length each) , I would like to know if I could have the option of doing live video streaming, or providing a download link to my customers. I also wonder if the same tool could also help with the invoicing and some way so as to avoid sharing the download link with others or even some DRM on the video file.

There are a lot of tools out there to sell digital downloadable products, but many of them are not specialized on selling videos and protecting copyrights (such as offering DRM) or controlling download link sharing and also several do not offer an easy and friendly invoicing workflow, ideally also I would prefer services that charge a commission on top of each sale rather than a fixed monthly amount.

Is there any recommended npm package for this purposes? If in the case that there's no complete already existing solution, how could I password protect the downloadable link or restrict the sharing of the download link with JS?

I will appreciate you pointing me out in the right direction.

Many thanks!

Sebastian

Comment: Does Drupal have anything to offer you? It's probably the most popular eCommerce suite, with many plugins. We even have [a sister site](v) for Drupal questions